# data displays as [object object] in jquery ajax in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

am displaying data on 2 dropdowns such that the options in the second dropdown depend on the option selected in the first dropdown. the problem is upon selecting the first the second dropdown displays the options as  [object Object] in the 2nd dropdown. how can I change this to display the data as the value in the database. this is my jquery script. am thinking the problem might be in my script but i haven't been able to figure out where it is actually.

my jquery script

```js
$(document).on('change', '.county', function() {

    var cnty_id = $(this).val();
    var div = $(this).parent();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'getshippingprice',
        data: {
            'id': cnty_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('.town').html('<option disabled selected value=" ">Select Your City</option>');
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('.town').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function() {}
    });
});
```

Here's the code for my blade file:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="country-select">
        <label>County <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <select id="cty_id" class="county form-control">
            <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Choose Your County</option> @foreach($delivaddresses as $address) <option value="{{ $address->id }}">{{ $address->county }}</option> @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="checkout-form-list">
        <label>Town / City <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <select class="town form-control" name="town">
            <option value=" " disabled="true" selected="true">Select Your City</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$.each(data, function(key, value) {` jquery [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) signature is `$.each(data, function(index, object)` so would be `$.each(data, function(i, o) { ... '<option value="'+o.key+'">'+o.value+'</option>'...`

Comment: You have `console.log(data)` so why not add `console.log(key, value)` inside your `$.each` to see what you're actually getting.

Comment: `"[object Object]"` is shown when you convert an object to a string, you need the object properties.

Comment: @freedomn-m returns "undefined" how can i define them

Comment: `o.key` `o.value` where just suppositions based on your existing code, but will need to be based on your data, which you've not provided... surely you know your own data?  What's the output of `console.log(data)` (or part of it...)

Comment: @freedomn-m its shows the ids and values for the option selected on the console.log..the code above you answered works very well but returns undefined on the second dropdown but on the console.log but on the browser it shows "undefined".